# Can I curb Honey's grab for my data by only using it within a separate profile?

Tags: privacy, browser-extensions

I'm interested in getting a coupon code for an online purchase and to this end [Honey](https://www.joinhoney.com/) is nice, but when it comes to protecting my data Honey is really invasive. Can I curb Honey's hunger for my whole browser interaction by only using it within a separate profile of, say Chrome? And if so, is it enough to close the browser window after I've used Honey to not let them have more of my data than just in the session under that profile?

The Chrome browser extension would only be active in that "Honey" profile.

Comment: So, your intent is to use the browser extension? Why not use a 2nd browser just for this purpose?

Comment: Sure, I could do that, but then I'd have assign separate resources just for that purpose. What if I don't use the browser extension, but just go the site through the separate profile? Would that still expose me to the data collection on the other profile?

Answer (score 1):

The only people who can give you a 100% complete answer are those who work at Honey's code. However, there are some things we can guess.

Quoting their [privacy policy](https://www.joinhoney.com/en/privacy):

> Honey automatically collects information to ensure that our products work correctly on different devices and browsers. This includes data like
>
> - the type of device you're using
> - the device's unique ID (where available)
> - operating system
> - browser type
> - IP address
> - event stamp
> - error logs

Which is, more often than not, enough to track you cross-profiles (they just need to send this data to their server, which they do, and then extract it again when you visit any page with their cookie/tracking script installed). The bright side is that, according to them, they don't always do that:

> Honey does not track your search engine history, emails, or your browsing on any site that is not a retail website (a site where you can shop and make a purchase).

While the privacy policy is not 100% clear on this, the wording of many parts speak of "selected retail websites", which makes me think that they intend to only collect your data on a Honey-compatible website (which makes sense: they probably have little interest in websites they can't provide coupons for).

So, to answer your question: the data collected by Honey can be used to track you cross-profile and, maybe, even cross-browser. Maybe they don't do it, maybe they do, but the only way to make sure they can't is to spoof your IP address and device ID (the latter might be pretty hard to spoof, depending on what they mean and how the information is collected).